# How to know which annoation has been tapped?

Tags: iphone, ios4, mapkit

I am doing mapview. In my app there is code which gets current location of the user in latitude and longitude. Using this coordinates i am creating a soap request. In response i will get information(zip,city,state,country,coordinates) of locations. I have saved this information in NSDictionary.

This is the code for creating annotation.

```
MapLocation *annotation = [[MapLocation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location ownerInst:ownerInstitution];
    [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    [annotation release];


- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation {

MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
annView.canShowCallout = YES;

UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(infoButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;


annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
return annView;
}
```

This is the delegate method when user tap the detaildisclosurebutton in the callout.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

On the tap of detail disclosure button new view will be loaded. And in this new view, information which i retrieved from the server will be displayed.

Upto this everything is fine. I have more than one annotations in the map. But when particular annotation is tapped how will i implement the code to show the information (which i get from the server)related to that annotation.

I hope I am clear in expressing my problem. Feel free to ask further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MKAnnotationView *view` which you get from the delegate method contains the Annotation. You can store all information in your MapLocation class you need to display.

```
MapLocation *annotation = [[MapLocation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location ownerInst:ownerInstitution];
[mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
[mapView addAdditionalCustomInformation: SomeInfo]; //you need to write your custom methods for that ;)
[annotation release];
```

Comment: Ok. There are more than one annotations. How will i implement further to get information corresponding to that annotation.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583501/assign-dynamic-data-to-detail-view-when-clicking-callout-info-button     this is the link which has a same question. Hope you can get some more clarity looking at that question also.

Comment: Yeah i understand what you want but it seems my answer was unclear. ;)

Comment: Every time you add an annotation to your map you can store custom information in it. I don't know where you get that from you have to handle that on your own. By extending your MapLocation class with methods or properties.
When the user taps the calloutAccessory you can pass your information from this particular annotation to your new viewController in the delegate method.

Comment: All the information is in MapLocation class. Now what to implement in the method - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control

Comment: So you want to know, how to pass the data in MapLocation to the new ViewController? Can you post your implementation of `(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control`as far you have it?

Comment: Nop. that i did. I passed the data to the MapLocation. But i do not know what to implement in the method (MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control